# FileDialog exception

Tags: .net, exception, c++-cli

I am trying to use `OpenFileDialog` as in the code below, but the compiler shows the exception `System::NullReferenceException`, once I put the the code between `try` and `catch` block, no exception is thrown, but now dialog is shown!?

```
try 
{ 
    if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    { 
         this->textBox18->Text=openFileDialog1->FileName->ToString();  

    } 
} 
catch(System::NullReferenceException^ e){ e->Message;}
```

Comment: have you created `openFileDialog1` before using it?

Comment: like this `private: System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog^  openFileDialog1;` ??

Comment: @Aan No. Like this `OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;`

Comment: @Nacereddine Thank you this solved the problem, but what is the difference between your segment and my segment of code?

Comment: the exception could be because FileName in openFileDialog1 is null and the ToString() is throwing null reference exception. Check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create an instance of the `OpenFileDialog` class before using it. In this code segment:

```
private: System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1;
```

You are just declaring a variable of the type `OpenFileDialog` (initialized with `null`) but you need to instantiate it before being able to use it with

```
OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
```